# How can Nokia decrypt HTTPS data?

Tags: encryption, tls, man-in-the-middle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can real end-to-end SSL encryption be made?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27820/can-real-end-to-end-ssl-encryption-be-made)

Regarding [this piece of news](http://gigaom.com/2013/01/10/nokia-yes-we-decrypt-your-https-data-but-dont-worry-about-it/), I wonder how can Nokia so easily decrypt HTTPS data?

As I understand the data is encrypted by a public key on user-end, and can only be decrypted by the private key. However, I assume Nokia doesn't have the private key and they cannot brute force the data either. In that case, how are they doing it?

Comment: See: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27820/can-real-end-to-end-ssl-encryption-be-made

Comment: Man on the Tee proxy. He's not in the middle, he's your identical twin asking for a second identical bagel.